# How can I save R plots with special characters in ggplot2?

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, package, special-characters

suddenly I have a problem to use `emojifont` package in R. The error message is:

```
> library(emojifont)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘emojifont’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'sysfonts', details:
  call: font_add("sans", sans.r, sans.b, sans.i, sans.bi, NULL)
  error: freetype: cannot open resource, error code 1
```

For plots I use `ggplot2` package and using the `emojifont` package I was able to save R plots with all (slovak) characters with the command:

```
pdf("garch_t.pdf")
grid.arrange(garch_st_plot, garch_vt_plot, nrow = 2, ncol = 1)
dev.off()
```

and the plot looked like this one:
[GARCH_plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TEXOC.jpg)

where the x-axis is named as Časový horizont *t*. But now without `emojifont` package I only have Casový horizont *t*.

I googled that for some people this issue was solved by installation of XQuartz (https://www.xquartz.org/), but not for me since I can not open .dmg file.

Any advice, please?

Comment: (a) Try re-installing `install.packages("emojifont")`, (b) Are you actually trying to use emoji, or only Slovak characters? Does `emojifont` provide Slovak characters? Maybe something else changed, perhaps the `freetype` resource is needed for both emoji and Slovak characters... If no emoji, perhaps try [ragg](https://github.com/r-lib/ragg) (c) What system are you on? Windows?

Comment: @GregorThomas, (a) re-installation did not helped., (b) I actually do not use/want to use any emojis. I just wanted to Slovak characters be in the R plot after saving it as pdf file and when I try it for the first time, the installing `emojifont` package helped to do this. And what is freetype resource? Some package in R? (c)I'm on Windows.